# Removing subscription groups from app review

Tags: app-store-connect, app-store-connect-api

Recently my app was rejected because I have accidentally included two subscription groups that I did not intend to sell. In the current App Store Connect UI, I don't see a way to remove the subscription groups from this version, or entirely from the account. These items have never been on sale. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks!